# Only MSVC able to compile this code

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

Following code compiles fine on MSVC but chockes on gcc/Xcode.

In test1.h:

```
template<class T, class T2>
#ifdef WIN32
class __declspec(dllexport) Base
#else
class Base
#endif
{
protected:
    struct Impl;
    Impl *pimpl;
    virtual int Baz(std::vector<T2> &errorMsg) = 0;
public:
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
    Impl &GetTableVector() { return *pimpl; };
    virtual int Foo(T *param, std::vector<T2> &errorMsg) = 0;
    virtual int Bar(std::vector<T2> &errorMsg) = 0;
};

template<class T, class T2> struct Base<T, T2>::Impl
{
    std::vector<Table> m_tables;
};

template<class T, class T2> Base<T, T2>::~Base()
{
    delete pimpl;
}
```

In test2.h:

```
template <class T, class T2>
#ifdef WIN32
class __declspec(dllexport) Derived : public Base<T, T2>
#else
class Derived : public Base<T, T2>
#endif
{
public:
    Derived();
    virtual ~Derived();
    virtual int Foo(T *param, std::vector<T2> &errorMsg);
    virtual int Bar(std::vector<T2> &errorMsg);
protected:
    void GetErrorMessage(int code, T2 &errorMsg);
    virtual int Baz(std::vector<T2> &errorMsg);
};
```

In test2.cpp:

```
template<class T, class T2> Derived<T, T2>::Derived() : Base<T, T2>()
{
    pimpl = new Impl;
}
```

The error message is:

```
error: pimpl was not declared in this scope.
```

Well, this variable is declared in the base class as protected and so should be visible to the derived class.

The weird thing is - that code was compiling fine without using templates.

Any idea how do I fix it?

Thx.

Comment: Your `Derived` constructor delegates to itself, presumably you meant to call the `Base` constructor.

Comment: Try `this->pimpl`.

Comment: @user657267, fixed. Just a typo, sorry.

Comment: @n.m., got a different error: "expected type-specifier before Impl",

Comment: You'll also need `new typename Base<T, T2>::Impl`.

Comment: @Igor: the main difference between the compilers is that Visual C++ uses pre-standard single phase lookup. So with Visual C++ identifiers from a base that depends on template parameter, are visible in the derived class. With standard C++ and g++, they're not, so the compiler must be told about them (simple qualification can work for non-types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `test2.cpp` use this instead:

```
template<class T, class T2> Derived<T, T2>::Derived() : Base<T, T2>()
{
    Base<T, T2>::pimpl = new typename Base<T, T2>::Impl;
}
```

On Ubuntu 15.04 with gcc 4.9.2 I can confirm that it compiles.

Comment: Tried it. Works on both compilers. And works on Xcode.